# check if string is equal to a word and a number

Tags: javascript

I have an object that contains a string as a property. I want to check that this property is not equal to some word, followed by a space and a number. For instance, something like this:

```
var TheWordToCheck = "SomeWord";

if (TheObject['SomeProperty'] !== (TheWordToCheck + ' ' + 2)) {...}
if (TheObject['SomeProperty'] !== (TheWordToCheck + ' ' + 3)) {...}
```

In this example, the code checks for only `"SomeWord 2"` and `"SomeWord 3"`. How can I simplify this where it checks any numbers?

Thanks.

Comment: `if (!TheObject['SomeProperty'].match(/^TheWord\s\d$/))`

Comment: @adeneo: ok, cool; just put it in as an answer so I can accept it.

Comment: Sure, it's untested, but the logic should work, you might have to tweak the regex, but as it stands it should match the string, a space, and a number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a regex and the `match()` method (untested)

```
var reg = new RegExp("^"+TheWordToCheck+"\\s\\d$")

if (!TheObject['SomeProperty'].match(reg) {...
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/886Y9/)

Comment: Just noticed: TheWordToCheck is a variable but in your regex it's a literal.

Comment: You can use the Regex constructor

Answer (score 0):

depends on the range of numbers you need to check, if it is static or is less than a maximum value, you can use a loop and append the loop variable with the string and check

```
for (var i=0;i<maxNumber;i++)
{ 
if (TheObject['SomeProperty'] !== (TheWordToCheck + ' ' + i)) {...
                 break;
                 }
}
```

or you can use regex as suggested in the comments

Comment: then go for the regex method, its smarter anyways. i thought you may not be willing to go into regex, which would be easier this time as somebody else has given the expression, but would be hard to make the next time if you do not have a good understanding of it.

Comment: also, why were you looking to avoid this, any particular drawback ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regular expression to check this:

```
var TheWordToCheck = "SomeWord";
var TheObject = {
    "SomeProperty": "SomeWord 100"
};

var pattern = new RegExp(TheWordToCheck + ' \\d', 'g');
if (TheObject['SomeProperty'].match(pattern) != null) { ... }
```

Note that you have to do the backslashes twice in order to make sure that the first one is escaped in the pattern. You should also use the RegEx constructor in order to be able to use a variable in your pattern.